# how to iterate through an array of functions

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

so i have an array:

```
var cycle = Array<(Void -> Void)>()
```

and i have a function called addToArray, which adds functions that i have created to an array like this:

```
    func addToArray(){


    cycle.append(ani1)
    cycle.append(ani2)
    cycle.append(ani3)
    cycle.append(ani4)
    cycle.append(ani5)

}
```

i am now at the point where i would like to iterate through this array, would a for loop be the best option? And how would i go about doing it? would it be something like the code below?

```
    func cycleArray(){

    for var index = 0; index <= 3; index++ {


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite simple just work like with regular array.
This is my example from playground:

```
func first() -> Int{
    return 1
}
func second() -> Int{
    return 2
}

var cycle = Array<(Void -> Int)>()

cycle.append(first)
cycle.append(second)

for function in cycle {
    print(function())
}
```